# Каким образом сделать регистрацию в боте Telegram используя 1С?

Tags: telegram-bot, 1с

Связал бота telegram и программу 1С, и нужна помощь в его функционировании
Каким образом сделать так, что когда человек пишет /start, бот ему отвечает: Приветствую {user}, ты попал в бота который будет уведомлять тебя о твоих заказах, для дальнейшего просмотра зарегистрируйте здесь свой номер телефона: (пользователь вводит номер телефона).
Вы успешно зарегистрировались, далее будет работать с вашим номером

```
Процедура ОбработкаСообщенияСистемыВзаимодействия(Сообщение, ДополнительныеПараметры)

Ответ = СистемаВзаимодействия.СоздатьСообщение(Сообщение.Обсуждение);   

ТекстСообщения = Сообщение.Текст;
ЧастиСообщения = СтрРазделить(ТекстСообщения, Символы.ПС);
ТекстОтвета = "Вы написали:
    |> " + СтрСоединить(ЧастиСообщения, Символы.ПС + "> ");
    

Ответ.Текст = ТекстОтвета;

Ответ.Записать();
```

КонецПроцедуры